# Castle ActiveRecord Error With View: NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException for generated key

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm mapping a view using ActiveRecord, which means I need a primary key.  I don't have one, so I'm using ROW_NUMBER() to create one in the view definition to placate the system. However, I don't seem to know how to map it properly.  I'm getting:

Could not find field 'stupidID' in class 'blah_blah'
NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find field 'stupidID' in class 'blah_blah'

My mapping looks like this.  There is no

```
    public long? stupidID;
    [PrimaryKey("StupidId", Access = PropertyAccess.NosetterLowercaseUnderscore)]
    public long? StupidId
    {
      get { return stupidID; }
    }
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: I worked around this issue by creating a composite key instead.

Comment: using a composite PK is **guaranteed** to make you suffer. Instead, solve the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

`NosetterLowercaseUnderscore` means that by convention a prefix '_' is used and it's lowercase, so the field should be called `_stupidid` instead of `stupidID`.

Also, the PK shouldn't be a nullable type. I'd use `long` instead of `long?`

Comment: Yeah, I was using a generator to make the class, and it always set that Access modifier. However, if you look at the error message, you can see that it was looking for a field without an underscore anyway (hence the problem)

Comment: long? shouldn't be there, sure, but that wasn't the problem either.

Comment: @Jeff : yes it **is** the problem, see the docs: https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Attributes/PropertyAccess.cs#L184